# How to Edit JSON using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a `JSONObject` inside a `JSONArray` (like the below JSON). Now I have to add the `productID` value as the `KEY` of the Object like the `Required JSON`. I'm trying to do this via javascript. But I can't get the desired output.

I tried to find any solution on Google. But it doesn't work out. 
Can anyone guide me how to do this or show me any references ?

**ORIGINAL JSON**

```
[
{
        "productID": "C05M01P001",
        "productName": "Aashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat (முழு கோதுமை)",
        "productUnit": "1 kg",
        "productPrice": "Rs.50.00",
        "productSellingPrice": "",
        "productSID": "",
        "productImage": "http://www.thechert.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/asvd-attaplain-atta-large-500x500.jpg",
        "productDescription": "Ashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat 1 kg..",
        "productCID": "C05",
        "productMID": "M01"
    },
..... it goes on
]
```

**Required JSON**

```
{
    "C05M01P001" : {
        "productID": "C05M01P001",
        "productName": "Aashirvaad Atta - Whole ",
        "productUnit": "1 kg",
        "productPrice": "Rs.50.00",
        "productSellingPrice": "",
        "productSID": "",
        "productImage": "http://www.thechenart.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/asvd-attaplain-atta-large-500x500.jpg",
        "productDescription": "Ashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat 1 kg",
        "productCID": "C05",
        "productMID": "M01"
    }, 
..... it goes on
}
```

Comment: Result is not valid javascript.

Comment: The "required JSON" is invalid. And that's not JSON but an array of objects

Comment: You `required JSON` can be a object, not an array.

Comment: Your result cannot be what you suggest, but could be either an array of objects e.g. `[ { "C05M01P001: {...}}, {"C05M01P002": {...}} ]` or (probably makes more sense) a single object `{"C05M01P001: {...}, "C05M01P002": {...}}` - which do you need?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. As Err Hunter Suggested, it is a JSON Object.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "json object". JSON is a string data format

Comment: @user3467240 did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with a single loop,

```js
var inputJson = [{
  "productID": "C05M01P001",
  "productName": "Aashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat (முழு கோதுமை)",
  "productUnit": "1 kg",
  "productPrice": "Rs.50.00",
  "productSellingPrice": "",
  "productSID": "",
  "productImage": "http://www.thechennaikart.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/asvd-attaplain-atta-large-500x500.jpg",
  "productDescription": "Ashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat 1 kg..",
  "productCID": "C05",
  "productMID": "M01"
}, {
  "productID": "C05M01P002",
  "productName": "XYZ - Whole Wheat (முழு கோதுமை)",
  "productUnit": "1.3 kg",
  "productPrice": "Rs.40.00",
  "productSellingPrice": "",
  "productSID": "",
  "productImage": "http://www.thechennaikart.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/asvd-attaplain-atta-large-500x500.jpg",
  "productDescription": "XYZ - Whole Wheat 1.3 kg..",
  "productCID": "C05",
  "productMID": "M01"
}];


var outputJson = {};

inputJson.forEach((singleProduct) => {
  outputJson[singleProduct.productID] = singleProduct;
});

console.log(outputJson);
```

And output will be,

```
{
    "C05M01P001": {
        "productID": "C05M01P001",
        "productName": "Aashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat (முழு கோதுமை)",
        "productUnit": "1 kg",
        "productPrice": "Rs.50.00",
        "productSellingPrice": "",
        "productSID": "",
        "productImage": "http://www.thechennaikart.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/asvd-attaplain-atta-large-500x500.jpg",
        "productDescription": "Ashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat 1 kg..",
        "productCID": "C05",
        "productMID": "M01"
    },
    "C05M01P002": {
        "productID": "C05M01P002",
        "productName": "XYZ - Whole Wheat (முழு கோதுமை)",
        "productUnit": "1.3 kg",
        "productPrice": "Rs.40.00",
        "productSellingPrice": "",
        "productSID": "",
        "productImage": "http://www.thechennaikart.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/asvd-attaplain-atta-large-500x500.jpg",
        "productDescription": "XYZ - Whole Wheat 1.3 kg..",
        "productCID": "C05",
        "productMID": "M01"
    }
}
```

Comment: The Fonts in the product name are not showing properly. How Can i Fix it ?

Comment: You have to use correspond language font/characterset in your website. Google for `Bamini Tamil` font, and how to include and use fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` method, which accepts a `callback` method and applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

```js
var json=[
{
        "productID": "C05M01P001",
        "productName": "Aashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat (முழு கோதுமை)",
        "productUnit": "1 kg",
        "productPrice": "Rs.50.00",
        "productSellingPrice": "",
        "productSID": "",
        "productImage": "http://www.thechennaikart.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/asvd-attaplain-atta-large-500x500.jpg",
        "productDescription": "Ashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat 1 kg..",
        "productCID": "C05",
        "productMID": "M01"
    },
    {
        "productID": "C05M01P002",
        "productName": "Aashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat (முழு கோதுமை)",
        "productUnit": "1 kg",
        "productPrice": "Rs.50.00",
        "productSellingPrice": "",
        "productSID": "",
        "productImage": "http://www.thechennaikart.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/asvd-attaplain-atta-large-500x500.jpg",
        "productDescription": "Ashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat 1 kg..",
        "productCID": "C05",
        "productMID": "M01"
    }
]
console.log(json.reduce(function(object,item){
    object[item.productID]=item;
    return object;
},{}));
```

Comment: That was not quite what was asked. However it is preferable to have `{"C05M01P001": {
      "productID": "C05M01P001",` to `[ "C05M01P001": {
      "productID": "C05M01P001",`

Comment: Yes, closest match to OP's question.

Comment: @ErrHunter: Well, maybe. Better to get clarification first, before posting speculative answers that may not be what the OP needs at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I agree to it.

Comment: OP changed the question to have correct object structure so you just need to drop the outer array

Comment: Looks like a job for `reduce` now.

Comment: I changed the function to `reduce`.

Comment: The Fonts in the product name are not showing properly. How Can i Fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You just loop through the array, creating an object with properties keyed by the `item` property. You can use a simple `forEach`:

```
var updated = {};
original.forEach(function(entry) {
  updated[entry.productID] = entry;
});
```

```js
var original = [
{
        "productID": "C05M01P001",
        "productName": "Aashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat (முழு கோதுமை)",
        "productUnit": "1 kg",
        "productPrice": "Rs.50.00",
        "productSellingPrice": "",
        "productSID": "",
        "productImage": "http://www.thechennaikart.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/asvd-attaplain-atta-large-500x500.jpg",
        "productDescription": "Ashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat 1 kg..",
        "productCID": "C05",
        "productMID": "M01"
    }
];
var updated = {};
original.forEach(function(entry) {
  updated[entry.productID] = entry;
});
console.log(updated);
```

(Or even just a `for` loop.)

Or `reduce`, although some consider this an "abusage":

```
var updated = original.reduce(function(obj, entry) {
  obj[entry.productID] = entry;
  return obj;
}, {});
```

```js
var original = [
{
        "productID": "C05M01P001",
        "productName": "Aashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat (முழு கோதுமை)",
        "productUnit": "1 kg",
        "productPrice": "Rs.50.00",
        "productSellingPrice": "",
        "productSID": "",
        "productImage": "http://www.thechennaikart.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/asvd-attaplain-atta-large-500x500.jpg",
        "productDescription": "Ashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat 1 kg..",
        "productCID": "C05",
        "productMID": "M01"
    }
];
var updated = original.reduce(function(obj, entry) {
  obj[entry.productID] = entry;
  return obj;
}, {});
console.log(updated);
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally `.reduce()` is the tool for this job but since it's already given, for a variety you can also try a recursive approach as follows;

```js
var os = [{x:1,y:"test"},{x:2,y:"more"},{x:3,y:"test"}],
folder = (a,p) => a.length && Object.assign({[a[0][p]]:a[0]},folder(a.slice(1),p));
console.log(folder(os,"x"));
```

Though in JS if you have a very long array of objects (100K+) I wouldn't recommend using recursive approaches at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = [
{
        "productID": "C05M01P001",
        "productName": "Aashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat (முழு கோதுமை)",
        "productUnit": "1 kg",
        "productPrice": "Rs.50.00",
        "productSellingPrice": "",
        "productSID": "",
        "productImage": "http://www.thechennaikart.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/asvd-attaplain-atta-large-500x500.jpg",
        "productDescription": "Ashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat 1 kg..",
        "productCID": "C05",
        "productMID": "M01"
    },
    {
        "productID": "C05M01P002",
        "productName": "Aashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat (முழு கோதுமை)",
        "productUnit": "1 kg",
        "productPrice": "Rs.50.00",
        "productSellingPrice": "",
        "productSID": "",
        "productImage": "http://www.thechennaikart.com/image/cache/Product_Images_2016/asvd-attaplain-atta-large-500x500.jpg",
        "productDescription": "Ashirvaad Atta - Whole Wheat 1 kg..",
        "productCID": "C05",
        "productMID": "M01"
    }
];

var obj = {};

for (var i in jsonObj) {
  obj[jsonObj[i].productID] = jsonObj[i];
}

console.log(obj);
```